# Turn off counting line numbers in less command

Tags: linux, opensuse, less-unix

In openSUSE 12.2, the `less` command counts line numbers when the file is opened. This causes a lot of delays when working with huge files. Is there a way to disable this option?

Answer (score 11):

My `less` (cygwin) has a `-n` option to suppress that default behavior. Equivalent to the long version `--line-numbers`. Do `man less` to see your `less`'s options.

Comment: `-n` option counts the bytes instead of number of lines. But yes, it is fast and saves from delay of counting line numbers of huge files.

Comment: Probably because bytes can be `seek`ed (where lines generally can't, without using some sort of index on newlines).